# Strange fstab file

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

I have extracted and unpacked the recovery file of my android device.

The /ect/fstab file contains line that is strange for me.

I have uploaded the file at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HAeJpcbx)

The line that mounts the /mnt/external_sd, it's correct? the "mnt_flags and options" column is correct? The value "/dev/block/mmcblk0" is a valid value?

```
# Android fstab file.
#<src>                                       <mnt_point>         <type>        <mnt_flags and options>       <fs_mgr_flags>
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1                         /mnt/external_sd     vfat       /dev/block/mmcblk0        defaults
```

EDIT:

I have replaced the value "/dev/block/mmcblk0" to "defaults" and have fixed my problems with the recovery (I'm porting CWM for my device)

What means the value "/dev/block/mmcblk0"? What are the impications to change this value? I can't find documentation about the proper format of fstab for CWM.

Comment: looks plausible at first glance, but to know if it's right we'd need to know what phone you have

Comment: It's and android TV device. MXQ-4K.
I'm trying to port the CWM recovery. Boots but I can't mount a lot of partitions like /mnt/external_sd  and /mnt/internal_sd